# Proof of $p \mid (x,y) \Rightarrow p \mid x$ and $p \mid y$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I have some troubles with the next step in my book:

- $p$ is a prime number
- $(x,y)$ is the GCD of $x$ and $y$

Why is it true that:
$p \mid (x,y) \Rightarrow p \mid x$ and $ p \mid y$

Comment: This is not anything special about prime numbers. The factors of $(x,y)$ are precisely the common factors of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: That's basically the definition of the GCD.

Answer (score 3):

Because if we say $(x,y) = g$, then $x = ng$ and $y = mg$ with $(m,n) = 1$. Therefore, if $p|g$, obviously, $p|x$ and $p|y$.

Comment: Is  p∣x and p∣y ⇒ p∣(x,y) also true?

Comment: Yes, that's also true. If $p|x$ and $p|y$, then $x = pm$, $y = pn$. Then we have $(x,y) = p\cdot(m,n)$ so $p | (x,y)$.